# Fetch total no of arrays instead of data from api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch the total number of arrays of validators (example-1038)
from JSON file using this code but it is not working.

What is wrong with my code?

```
let fetchRes = fetch("https://avax.dev/data/validators.json"); 

// fetchRes is the promise to resolve 
// it by using.then() method 
fetchRes
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(d => {
     console.log(d)
     
     let len = Object.keys(validators).length;

     console.log(len);
 });
```

Comment: what is `validators` - where is it declared? where is it given a value? `console.log(d.validators.length)` would give you the length of that response array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the code too.

You were trying to access the `validators` array outside `.then`. So the data (`d`) we get back is what I am using to get the `validators`.

```js
let fetchRes = fetch("https://avax.dev/data/validators.json");

// fetchRes is the promise to resolve

// it by using.then() method

fetchRes
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((d) => {
    console.log(d);
    let len = d.validators.length;
    console.log(len);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, "d" is an object. Inside the object "validators" is a key with array as value (key: value pair). So in order to access the validators length you will have to do "d.validators.length".

```js
let fetchRes = fetch("https://avax.dev/data/validators.json"); 

   
fetchRes.then(res => res.json())
.then(d => { 
    console.log(d);
    //get the array length using d.validators.length
    console.log(d.validators.length)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently are trying to get the length of the validators field outside the promise resolution. What is actually happening is that these lines

```
var len = Object.keys(validators).length;
console.log(len);
```

run before the `console.log(d)`. On top of this the variable `d` is not available outside of the `.then()`

to fix this just move the code inside the `.then()`

```
fetchRes
.then(res => res.json())
.then(d => {    
    const length = d.validators.length;
    console.log(length);
})
```